# Infer child types of TypeScript Object and Array

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics

I want to have a function that returns the children of any collection in a redux-style store in TypeScript. A collection can be an Object or an Array. I also want to declare my function type safe using generics, such that it infers the type(s) of the children as the return type of the function.

Take the simplified example below. The store looks as follows:

```
interface MessageStore {
  readonly messages: Message[];
  readonly messagesById: { [id: string]: Message };
}
```

And the generic function declaration looks as follows:

```
function getMessages<S extends keyof MessageStore, T extends MessageStore[S]>(
  path: S
): T[keyof T][];
```

When accessing `messagesById` and `messages`, I want the inferred return type to be `Message[]`. When accessing `messagesById` (an `Object`), this is indeed the case. However, when accessing `messages` (an `Array`), the inferred return type is a complex union type that I did not expect.

```
// Correctly infers `Message[]` as the result type when accessing an object
const fromObject = getMessages("messagesById");

// Infers a complex union type as the result when accessing an array
// What is going wrong here?
const fromArray = getMessages("messages");
```

[Working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-e6ivzi)

I expect my function declaration should be different, but I do not understand how I should change it. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: change `T[keyof T][]` to `T[number][]`?  That fits your example but maybe not your use case.   Perhaps you want `T extends Array<infer L> ? L[] : T[keyof T][]`?  Without more info I'm not sure.  Arrays are objects in JavaScript, but TypeScript [doesn't have a sense of "enumerable own keys"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726) so it can't do the same thing `Object.keys()` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `T extends Array<infer L> ? L[] : T[keyof T][]` is what I was looking for.

However, it causes some other typing issues inside of the function, where the returned values no longer match the declared return type. Is this due to the same issue you linked to?

[I have updated my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ei57lt?file=index.ts).

Comment: It's mostly due to the fact that the compiler can't really verify assignability to conditional types that depend on as-yet unspecified generic type parameters.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) and other related linked issues.  You'll have to use type assertions or overloads or something that loosens type safety to get this to work.